# How do i get code coverage on azure pipeline using coverlet and cobertura config?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-xplat-cli

I am trying to write YAML file for code coverage.

What is the correct way to get code coverage for my project in Azure pipelines using **coverlet** and **cobertura** configurations?

I have followed the same steps as running locally with CLI commands, but I am still getting zero coverage. My arguments are as follows:

```
--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --logger trx /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:Exclude="[xunit.*]*" /p:CoverletOutput=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\coverage.
```

Should I exclude my project while running the code coverage command? Any ideas on what might be wrong with my commands?

I tried all the steps found on internet. I verified commands comparing with the commands running locally in CMD with same commands.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce with same arguments for `dotnet test`:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet test
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    arguments: '--configuration Release --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --logger trx /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:Exclude="[xunit.*]* /p:CoverletOutput=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\coverage'
```

[image]

For `Xplat Code Coverage`, you need to add `PublishCodeCoverageResults@2` task after the test task, so that it will publish the coverage from the build.

```
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  inputs:
    summaryFileLocation: |
      $(Agent.TempDirectory)\**\coverage.*.xml
```

[image]

Note: checked on my side, even you have specified /p:CoverletOutput, it will still generate the coverage.cobertura.xml in $(Agent.TempDirectory) folder.

Comment: - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage from $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\coverage.cobertura.xml'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\coverage.cobertura.xml'
    reportDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\coverage'

i have already did the same. I am getting the format display in code coverage tabe but get no value. But i get values locally for same project

Comment: Please check the coverage.cobertura.xml location in your test task log, it should still be `D:\a\_temp\...`, please change `summaryFileLocation` to `$(Agent.TempDirectory)\**\coverage.*.xml` as i mentioned above, and it's recommended to use v2 task.

Comment: @AakashParmar, may i know if there's any update? You can check the details about  the coverage.covbertura.xml generated from the log, fix in the `PublishCodeCoverageResults@2` task remcommended. Let me know if you have any queries.